# how to get the result come from server

Tags: c++, ftp, winsock, visual-c++

at windows system, i am making a ftp client.

i use "FtpCommand" function to send one ftp command to ftp server.

so i want to know that how i can receive msg from ftp server after call "FtpCommand" function.

Comment: do you like to repeat yourself? do you like to repeat yourself? do you like to repeat yourself?

Comment: Just read the command channel - you should get a 3-digit code followed by a text message, (eg. '200 OK').

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the size of a file, you'll likely need to use the `FtpGetFileSize` function, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384159(v=vs.85).aspx.